# SQL Update (Delphi)

Tags: sql, delphi

I wonder if yo could help me with a really simple problem which I canot seem to solve.

Basically, I have created a voting system in Delphi 7. After the user has checked a check box to vote "Yes" I need to update my table "Rules" by increasing the field "Yes Votes" by one.

Here is where the problem comes in, for some reason, the table is *always* increased by a value of 2 instead of 1!

Please assist in anyway possible, I am very new to this so please be patient.

Here is my code: 
(Note: "bYes" is a boolean with the value from a checkbox.
       "RuleID" is a fieldname linking to a certain rule to be voted upon)

```
if bYes = True then
begin
  qry1.Active := False;
  qry1.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE rules SET [Yes votes] = [yes votes] + 1 WHERE ruleid = "1"';
  qry1.ExecSQL;
  qry1.Active := True;
end
else
  qry1.close;
qry1.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE rules SET [no votes] = [no votes] + 1 WHERE ruleid = "1"';
qry1.ExecSQL;
qry1.Open;
```

Comment: Besides the lack of `begin .. end `in the else branch also `qry1.Open` or `qry1.Active=True` should be removed as this leads depending on the component an extra perform of then SQL and depending on the component to an error. You only need to use qry1.ExecSQL.

Comment: @bummi : that's the reason for : `Problem : the table is always increased by a value of 2 instead of 1!` . Your comment, should be the answer.

Comment: Security note: don't forget to use SQL parameters ;)

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the component setting `qry1.Active := True;` or `qry1.Open;` will perform the sql for a second time and depending on the component will raise an additional exception after performing. You only need to call `qry1.ExecSQL;` within a `begin .. end` block.

```
begin
  if byes then // omitt = True
  begin
    qry1.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE rules SET [Yes votes] = [yes votes] + 1 WHERE ruleid = "1"';
    qry1.ExecSQL;
  end
  else
  begin   
    qry1.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE rules SET [no votes] = [no votes] + 1 WHERE ruleid = "1"';
    qry1.ExecSQL;
  end;
end;
```

another way of calling could be

```
begin
  if byes then // omitt = True
    qry1.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE rules SET [Yes votes] = [yes votes] + 1 WHERE ruleid = "1"'
  else
    qry1.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE rules SET [no votes] = [no votes] + 1 WHERE ruleid = "1"';
  qry1.ExecSQL;

end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Indenting your code would reveal you have missed a `begin`/`end` for your else block:

```
if bYes = True then
begin
    qry1.Active := False;
    qry1.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE rules SET [Yes votes] = [yes votes] + 1 WHERE ruleid = "1"';
    qry1.ExecSQL;
    qry1.Active := True;
end
else
    qry1.close;
qry1.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE rules SET [no votes] = [no votes] + 1 WHERE ruleid = "1"';
qry1.ExecSQL;
qry1.Open;
```

Additionally, you should make sure that `qry1.Active` and `qry1.Open` are not performing an additional execution of the query.

Comment: You beat me to it by seconds :)

Comment: Problem : `the table is always increased by a value of 2 instead of 1!` . In your code you do the same mistake as OP. Doing a `qry1.Open;` before changing the `sql` !!